# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime object

Tags: c#, exception, datetime, try-catch

```
try
{
    foreach (DataRow row in tempTable.Rows)
    {
        row["Start_Date"] = objUtil.ConvertDate(row["Start_Date"].ToString(), "yyyyMMdd").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss").Replace("12:00:00 AM", "").Trim();
        row["End_Date"] = objUtil.ConvertDate(row["End_Date"].ToString(), "yyyyMMdd").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss").Replace("12:00:00 AM", "").Trim();
        row["Start_Date_DateTime"] = row["Start_Date"];
        rowCnt++;
    }
    rowCnt = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row in tempTable1.Rows)
    {
        row["Start_Date"] = objUtil.ConvertDate(row["Start_Date"].ToString(), "yyyyMMdd").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss").Replace("12:00:00 AM", "").Trim();
        row["End_Date"] = objUtil.ConvertDate(row["End_Date"].ToString(), "yyyyMMdd").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss").Replace("12:00:00 AM", "").Trim();
        row["Start_Date_DateTime"] = row["Start_Date"];
        rowCnt++;
    }
    DataView _objdv = new DataView(tempTable);
    _objdv.Sort = "Suite_ID,Start_Date_DateTime ASC";
    DataTable _dt1 = _objdv.ToTable();
    objSuiteRate_Table = _dt1;
    DataView _objdv1 = new DataView(tempTable1);
    _objdv1.Sort = "Suite_ID,Start_Date_DateTime ASC";
    DataTable _dt2 = _objdv1.ToTable();
    objSuiteRate_TableGLB = _dt2;
    objPPCNorm.Connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    bool rethrow = BusinessLayerExceptionHandler.HandleException(ref ex);
    throw;
}
```

Error message is

> Couldn't store <08-30-2011 12:00:00> in DateTime column.Expected type
>   is DateTime object

Comment: I tried to fix the indentation of the code you posted to make it readable. This showed that there is a syntax error, I added the opening `try {` which you aparently forgot to paste...

Comment: Your formatting is a little screwed up there. If you indent your code by 4 spaces per line the code formatting should kick in. In any case, on which line does this exception occur? And what is objUtil in this context? We may need the code for ConvertDate if it's not part of the framework.

Comment: What language is this? Please add that as a tag so that people can help. #

Comment: Your datetime formatting changes seem excessive. You appear to be formatting a value as date only, then as date and time, and then stripping the time component off again but only if it is 12am. Perhaps try to simplify this if only for the next developer's sake.

Comment: Looks like you have tried to store a string into a column that is expecting a DateTime. What are you trying to achieve? You won't be able to change the DateTime formatting like this if they are not stored as strings (and nor should they be stored as strings). Instead, you need to change the format string associated with that column.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is very clear on what is wrong: you are putting a string into a datetime column:

```
objUtil.ConvertDate(row["Start_Date"].ToString(), "yyyyMMdd").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss").Replace("12:00:00 AM", "").Trim();
```

Will return a string. So you should remove the formatting part or make the column a string type:

remove formatting part and do the formatting in the component which displays the row:

```
objUtil.ConvertDate(row["Start_Date"].ToString(), "yyyyMMdd"); //**.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss").Replace("12:00:00 AM", "").Trim()**;
```

or change your row definition to type string.

Comment: I would say do NOT turn it into a string; the formatting should definitely be in the display component (as you did say).

Comment: I agree that how you present your data should be in the component which does the presentation of the data.